# Find string "user Input" in Google Sheet and display the cell it is found in

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google apps scripts and to javascript so forgive my ignorance.

I have a google sheet that contains a list of asset tag numbers for computers. It also contains the username, full name, and serial number of the laptop that the student is using.

Example:

StudentName     Username        AssetTag    SN

Student 1    username1  1002001   ####-##-####

Student 2   username2   1002002   ####-##-####

Student 3   username3   1002003 ####-##-####

Student 4   username4   1002004 ####-##-####

Student 5   username5   1002005 ####-##-####

Student 6   username6   1002006 ####-##-####

Student 7   username7       1002007 ####-##-####

Student 8   username8   1002008 ####-##-####

I need to be able to have the user input the asset tag number and have the script return the cell that it finds that number in, ideally to a variable.

The plan is to scan a barcode that inputs the asset tag and upon scanning have it fill in the rest of the information on a google form. So if someone scanned the barcode for 1002001 it would fill in the name, username, and SN fields for them. I'm hoping I can figure out the rest, but in order to do that I need the Cell that contains the asset number.

```
    function FindCell() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AmBYpL3aN9TZdDhZeGJnXzhRMkh2TkVTaHQtNnliSUE");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var cell = findCell();
  Logger.log(cell);
}
```

Thank you!

P.S. I have been reading on here for answers to batch scripts forever, but now I'm trying my hand at google's brand of javascript. This is my first post...

Comment: Thanks @Bonifacio2 . I added the little code that I have to my original question. I am just starting out on this javascript/google apps script thing and I may be in a little over my head. But the boss wants what the boss wants. I have no doubt that I can learn it, but I fear it is going to take a lot more time than he would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're kind of on the right track potter but with a few problems. The first being that your function is named FindCell (with upper case F) and it calls a very similarly named function findCell (with lower case f) that isn't shown anywhere.

The script supplied doesn't show how you are getting the asset tags to work with. You probably have some function that gets it and declares the input as a variable. You need to pass that variable to the function that searches for a match. Your function above would not actually search for anything.

This is what I would do ( with commented statements to explain what's going on):

```
function getScannedInput() { /*I'm simulating the function you probably have which gets the scanned input
  You'll have your script to get the input here*/

  var scannedInput = 1002001 //I hardcoded the number you gave just for example

  var myInfo = FindCell(scannedInput); // You need to pass the value of the scanned input to the function
                                       //returns this 2D array [[StudentName, userName, SN, cellAddress]]
  var StudentName = myInfo[0][0];
  var userName = myInfo[0][1];
  var SN = myInfo[0][2];
  var cellAddress = myInfo[0][3]; //You may not need this now.
  /*Bear in mind that if you still need to use the cellAddress you'll need to
    set variables for the ss and sheet in this function too.*/

//  * Now do stuff with StudentName, userName & SN *
}

function FindCell(scannedInput) { // You need to pass the value of the scanned input to the function
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1W3hkCk8foL7fQtmVkcU4ZP4eTbHT696cacR6a-sSeDY");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var myInfo = []; //Create an empty array to put your info in when found
  var found = false;
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; ++i) { // Loops through each row
    for (var j=0; j<values[i].length; ++j) { // Loops through each column
      if (values[i][j] == scannedInput) { // Checks for match to scannedInput
        myInfo.push(values[i][0]);//Adds StudentName to the array
        myInfo.push(values[i][1]);//Add username to the array
        myInfo.push(values[i][3]);//Adds SN to the array
        myInfo.push(sheet.getRange(i, j).getA1Notation()); /*If you still need to return the cell address - 
        Do you still need to? (I think probably not.) Delete if you don't*/
        found = true;
        break; // Breaks out of the j loop
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      break;  // Breaks out of the i loop if found is true i.e. scannedInput was found
    }
  }
  return [myInfo]; /*returns this array [StudentName, userName, SN, cellAddress]
  or [StudentName, userName, SN] if you didn't need cellAddress above.*/
}
```

Editted after OP pointed out that myInfo returns 2D array.
Here's a link to a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/shrosters.com/spreadsheets/d/1W3hkCk8foL7fQtmVkcU4ZP4eTbHT696cacR6a-sSeDY/edit#gid=0) used in above code.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much fullOfGAS! I'm going to take a while to go through all of that syntax and try to figure out why it does what you say it does, but it looks awesome! Looks to be exactly what I needed. Thanks a million!

Comment: fullOfGAS your code has gotten me much further than where I was, but I have another question (multiple questions, but I imagine it will be better to take things one at a time). What is the policy on this, should I "Answer my Question" with my new question to keep it all in one big question, should I edit my original question; and if so, do I leave the original also, or should I just open a whole new question? I don't want to do things the wrong way. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, it looks as if the info within the myInfo array is actually nested. Not sure if I said the right. If I do `var serialNumber = myInfo[0]` I get a response of _username1 ####-##-####_ . But if I do `var serialNumber = myInfo[0][0]` I get the correct response of _####-##-####_ . Not sure why this is, but I can deal with it. Just thought it might be pertinent in case anyone ever comes looking at this later.

Comment: You're welcome. Given the limit on no. of characters allowed in comments and my limited skills, whole new questions are your best option :) You can link back to this one if necessary. I can't even explain why myInfo changes to 2D array after it is returned. Probably something to do with values being a 2D array to start with but in the debugger myInfo shows as a single array until after the return line. Curious! I also should say that I incorrectly assumed SN stood for StudentName not serial number - I hadn't spotted SN in your table headings. I'll edit my answer.